ASP.NET Core Web API & Sharepoint authentication to create folders and upload files
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Web API with an Angular frontend, I'm looking into getting access to SharePoint (online) and create a folder for, and upload a file per client bases (so there could be x number client, and x number of files).
At the moment, I'm trying to figure out a connection to the SharePoint.
I'm using the following example from MS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins-modernize/from-csom-to-pnp-libraries
I wanted to use clientId, clientSecret, tenantID, and SiteUrl.
I have those in appsettings.json, and then configured in program.cs for link, with a class file for those settings, and finally a interface, with repository for the code.
My code :
public class SharePointService : ISharePointClientService
{
    private readonly SharePointSettings _settings;

    public SharePointService(IOptions<SharePointSettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings.Value;
    }

    public async Task<string> ConnectToSharePointAndGetSiteNameAsync()
    {
        var authManager = new AuthenticationManager(_settings.ClientId, _settings.ClientSecret, _settings.TenantId);
        
        using (var context = authManager.GetContext(_settings.SiteUrl))
        {
            var web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web, w => w.Id, w => w.Title);
            await context.ExecuteQueryRetryAsync();

            return context.Web.Title;
        }
    }
}

Then I use controller to call that method, for now I'm trying to get title, so that I responded back.
The error I get it's that it's asking for responseUrl.
Could someone point me in the direction, what I need to fix here or in the Azure app registration.
Thank you.
